# How to drag and drop in gnome 3

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3

I'm on Fedora 26 and I have the latest Gnome 3 that comes with it. I've been using Fedora for more than a year now, and to this day I have no clue how to drag and drop **easily**. I resize the windows so that I can see them both and the same time and dragging works. But it should be easier than that.

Is there an easy way to drag a file and drop it in a browser or some other software? I've read on reddit some tricks on how to do it, multiple workspaces and whatnot. But there should be no tricks, dragging and dropping should be the most easy task to do on any PC.

I've been using linux for almost 14 years and never had an issue like this, even on crunchbang linux which has openbox, i don't recall having this issue, it's driving me crazy.